# Disable live reload from yeoman angular project for ie9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, yeoman, livereload, yeoman-generator-angular

I believe the generators for an angular app include a grunt task of live reload. That doesn't seem to be working when hooked up to IE9 because IE9 does not support web sockets. Is there a way to disable live reload only for IE9? Or would you recommend poly filling if possible?

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does support it, or should. You could set livereload to false in your Gruntfile.js though